# complex Json Parsing in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

In my app, i want to parse json response which is in the format

```
{"quote":[{"orderId":"3209926"},{"totalpages":1}]}
```

below is the code which i had done,But the problem is how to get the "totalpages" value?

```
  try {
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("quote");
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                 {
        JSONObject offerObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        current.orderId = offerObject.getInt("orderId");
```

It shows error when i use

```
 current.totalpage= offerObject.getInt("totalpages");
```

Anybody knows how to parse this?THanks in advance

Comment: show your full implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [`getInt()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29), like other get-functions of [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) throw [`JSONException`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONException.html) if the object does not contain the key requested. Thus, before you request the key you should use [`hasKey()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) to determine whether the object contains the key.

For example, inside the for loop you can do the following:

```
JSONObject offerObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
if(offerObject.has("orderId") {
    current.orderId = offerObject.getInt("orderId");
}
if(offerObject.has("totalpages") {
    current.totalpage= offerObject.getInt("totalpages");
}
```

You can also add a flag and a check after the loop to ensure that both orderId and totalpages were present in the JSON data.

Comment: actually the response contains value for both orderid and totalpages.

Comment: Yes, but the sub-object examined in the first iteration of the loop does not contain "totalpages". Similarly, the sub-object examined in the second iteration does not contain "orderId". The sub-object examined in the first iteration is: `{"orderId":"3209926"}`. The sub-object examined in the second is: `{"totalpages":1}`.

Comment: In the loop iterating through the "quote" array, first check whether a property is present and if it is, then request its value, otherwise continue to check other properties. See the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why your json is having that structure. But if you want to parse it then you will have to do something like the following with the [has](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject offerObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        if(offerObject.has("orderId")) {
          current.orderId = offerObject.getInt("orderId");
        } else if(offerObject.has("totalpages")) {
          current.totalpage= offerObject.getInt("totalpages");
        }
}
```

Comment: i tried that but the response showing in logcat is                Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for totalpages

Comment: can you check the whats the result of offerObject.has("totalpages")

Comment: one more thing can are you using this http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html class